# What is the difference between using ConstrainedBox and Container widgets to give constraints to their child box?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I found that the only difference between the `Container()` and `ConstrainedBox()` widgets (if we want to constrain its child), is the more properties in the `Container()` widget to customize its child, but are there any other differences? and are there any performance differences and when it is efficient to use what?

Comment: this is what is built if `constraints` are not `null`: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c969b8af7b/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart#L447

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) does *not do anything* by itself. It is only a utility widget that delegates functionality to other widgets. This means that the `contraints` argument of a `Container` is **strictly equivalent** to [`ConstrainedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html).

If you take a look at the [source code for `Container`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/32be39bf16eb814d68d9213bc6f33463b918d8dc/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart#L410), you will find the following:

```dart
    if (constraints != null)
      current = ConstrainedBox(constraints: constraints, child: current);
```

#### → there is no difference.

```dart
Container(
  constraints: constraints,
  child: child,
)
// does strictly the same as
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: constraints,
  child: child,
)
```